# Angular 2 Routing with nested states

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router

I have this AppRoutingModule and HomeRoutingModule below. The first one contains some paths and imports the rest of paths from HomeRoutingModule.
My problem is how can I get the departmentId inside HomeComponent?
Actually my full path should be:

- 'domain:departments/:departmentId/profitability'
- 'domain:departments/:departmentId/loadFactor'
- ...

In each case I need to update only the departmentId in my url.

AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: 'app/components/home/home.module#HomeModule',
    data: { preload: true }
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home/departments/group/profitability', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

HomeRoutingModule

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'departments',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        { path: ':departmentId/fabi', component: FabiComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/loadFactor', component: LoadFactorComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/otp', component: OtpComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/profitability', component: ProfitabilityComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/revenue', component: RevenueComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/yield', component: YieldComponent }
    ]
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home/departments/group/profitability', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write like this in both routing files like.
In AppRoutingModule, Write down "departments" instead of home.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'departments',
    loadChildren: 'app/components/home/home.module#HomeModule',
    data: { preload: true }
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home/departments/group/profitability', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

And in HomeRoutingModule, Remove "departments" words after path: ...

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
        { path: ':departmentId/fabi', component: FabiComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/loadFactor', component: LoadFactorComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/otp', component: OtpComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/profitability', component: ProfitabilityComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/revenue', component: RevenueComponent },
        { path: ':departmentId/yield', component: YieldComponent }
    ]
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home/departments/group/profitability', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks